# WPF resize rectangle by manipulation does not maintain ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm facing a little problem. I'm designing an application on WPF that will run on Windows 8.1 tablet. I'm building a sort of "cropping" software (among other things).

To do so, I've created a Rectangle on my window, and followed the Microsoft walkthrough here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee649090(v=vs.100).aspx

Because I don't want to keep my rectangle square, I change their example by setting `Scale.Y` on `ManipulationDelta`

Here's the changed code

```
rectsMatrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
                    e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y,
                    e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                    e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);
```

But despite this, my rectangle is still resizing to square when I pinch to resize. I don't understand why or how to workaround this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF manipulation APIs don't support independently scaling X and Y while also being able to rotate.

Do this exercise... draw a rectangle and put two dots somewhere on it.  Now draw that same rectangle with those two dots moved diagonally away from each other.  Based on the deltas between those dots, how would you decide if the user was trying to rotate or independently scale X vs. Y or do both at the same time?  It's entirely ambiguous with the limited information we have.

This is why apps will often end up having specific 'handles' you need to touch to explicitly go into 'rotate' mode or 'X/Y resize mode'.  From an implementation perspective, you would handle the manipulation events on that handle (separate from the control itself) and set ManipulationOrigin and ManipulationStartingEventArgs.Mode accordingly.

*(Disclaimer:  I was part of the team that created these APIs several years ago)*

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Big up to you and your team for created this wonderful APIs ! You guys rocks. For my problem, I don't want to handle rotate, only resize, and I still don't know how to proceed :(

Comment: Ok if you don't want rotate, you need to handle ManipulationStarting and set ManipulationStartingEventArgs.Mode to Scale | Translate.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.input.manipulationstartingeventargs.mode(v=vs.100).aspx.  This might work... though I'm not 100% sure we supported independent X & Y even in this unambiguous case where rotation is disabled...

Comment: Yep, that's what I just tried and it doesn't work... Is there any event different of Delta to handle pinch, like in RT assemblys ?

Comment: This answer is not helpful. OP is not trying to rotate anything.

Answer (score 0):

From a mathematical view, I see two ways, first is simple compared to second one, but when you can make second work, it'll be more satisfying:

**First:**
You may decide that rotation or scaling is what user intended to do.
I would define two vectors: **v**, **w** and an integer, `d`, stands for "distance".

- Take the two point the user touched as `X` and `Y`. The distance between them would be `d`.
- Take the vector XY as **v**
- Take the new vector defined by user's fingers (X and Y) as **w**

Then you must compare length of **w** with `d` and the angle between **v** and **w**, take it as `alpha`.

For instance if `d`*sin(`degree`) < d/4 **->** should be rewritten as sin(degree)<0.25, then user intended to scale, otherwise he rotated the rectangle.

**Second:**
This would allow the user to rotate and scale simultaneously.

- Take X and Y, which define **v**.
- Take the rectangle, for example the left side and name that vector: **a**
- Rectangles can be defined as a vector and its connected (sheer) side (90 degrees), so take the length of the bottom side as `width`

Now if user does a transformation with the **v** vector, do the same with vector **a** and make width bigger/smaller.
hints: https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/

Comment: Where does OP say they need to rotate anything?